# Listview items different tab menu details

Tags: android, listview, menu, tabs, listviewitem

I want to do Listview items with different details while using tab menu.

Here is my app screens better to understand

http://tinypic.com/r/2niskna/9  My list view

http://i68.tinypic.com/9laoaq.png  and details page

I want to show different details when user click listview items. layout design is same but with different text details and images.

Maybe my codes are complex I dont know I am beginner in android, you can tell me the logic only then I can do it.

asker.java

```html
package com.example.fb.clashdeneme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by FB on 19.10.2016.
 */

public class asker extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ListView list;
    String [] askerbaslik;
    int [] images={R.drawable.barbar_icon,R.drawable.okcu_icon,R.drawable.dev_icon,R.drawable.goblin_icon,R.drawable.duvar_kirici_icon,R.drawable.balon_icon,
            R.drawable.buyucu_icon,R.drawable.sifaci_icon,R.drawable.ejderha_icon,R.drawable.pekka_icon,R.drawable.yavruejder_icon,R.drawable.madenci_icon};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        Resources res=getResources();
        askerbaslik= res.getStringArray(R.array.asker_adlari);


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ilyasadapter adapter=new ilyasadapter(this,askerbaslik,images);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


               switch (position){

                   case 0:
                       Intent intent_barbar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_barbar.putExtra("Position", position);
                       startActivity(intent_barbar);
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       Intent intent_okcu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_okcu.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_okcu);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       Intent intent_dev = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_dev.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_dev);
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       Intent intent_goblin = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_goblin.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_goblin);
                       break;
                   case 4:
                       Intent intent_duvarkirici = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_duvarkirici.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_duvarkirici);
                       break;
                   case 5:
                       Intent intent_balon = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_balon.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_balon);
                       break;
                   case 6:
                       Intent intent_buyucu = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_buyucu.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_buyucu);
                       break;
                   case 7:
                       Intent intent_sifaci= new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_sifaci.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_sifaci);
                       break;
                   case 8:
                       Intent intent_ejder = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_ejder.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_ejder);
                       break;
                   case 9:
                       Intent intent_pekka= new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_pekka.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_pekka);
                       break;
                   case 10:
                       Intent intent_yavruejder= new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_yavruejder.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_yavruejder);
                       break;
                   case 11:
                       Intent intent_madenci = new Intent(asker.this, Asker_detaylar.class);
                       intent_madenci.putExtra("intVariableName", position);
                       startActivity(intent_madenci);
                       break;
               }

 
           }
       });

    }


   public class ilyasadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context context;
        int [] images;
        String [] titlearray;

        ilyasadapter (Context c,String[] titles, int imgs[]) {
            super(c,R.layout.liste_tasarim,R.id.asker_baslik,titles);
            this.context=c;
           this.images=imgs;
            this.titlearray=titles;

        }

        class MyViewHolder {

            TextView mytitle;
            ImageView myimage;

            MyViewHolder(View v) {

                mytitle=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.asker_baslik);
                myimage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.asker_icon);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            View row=convertView;
            MyViewHolder holder=null;

            if (row==null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_tasarim, parent, false);
                holder=new MyViewHolder(row);

                row.setTag(holder);

                Log.d("test","creating a new row");
            }

            else
            {

                holder =(MyViewHolder) row.getTag();

                Log.d("test","Recycling stuff");
            }



            holder.myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);
            holder.mytitle.setText(titlearray[position]);

            return row;
        }




    }



}
```

Asker_detaylar.java

```html
package com.example.fb.clashdeneme;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by FB on 20.10.2016.
 */

public class Asker_detaylar extends AppCompatActivity  {


    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);


        switch (intValue) {
            case 0:

                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);

                break;
            case 1:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                //      TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                //   mTextView2.setText(R.string.aciklama2);

                break;
            case 2:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;

            case 3:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 4:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 5:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 6:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 7:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 8:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 9:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 10:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;
            case 11:
                setContentView(R.layout.detay_tasarim);
                break;


        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });


    }

   private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments [] = {"Genel Özellikler","Saldırı","Savunma","Yükseltme"};

        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Genel_tab();
                case 1:
                    return new Saldiri_tab();
                case 2:
                    return new Savunma_tab();
                case 3:
                    return new Yukseltme_tab();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }





    }
```

Genel_tab.java

```html
package com.example.fb.clashdeneme;

/**
 * Created by FB on 22.10.2016.
 */

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * Created by filip on 8/21/2015.
 */
public class Genel_tab extends Fragment {
    int pos=0;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.genel_tab_layout, container, false);


        final String [] isimlerarray;
        final  String ozellikler1,ozellikler2,ozellikler3,ozellikler4,ozellikler5;

        final int [] resimler={R.drawable.barbarian1and2,R.drawable.barbarian1and2,R.drawable.barbarian3and4,R.drawable.barbarian3and4,R.drawable.barbarian5,R.drawable.barbarian6,
                R.drawable.barbarian7};


        Button ileri = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ileri_btn);
        Button geri = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.geri_btn);

        Resources res = getResources();

        isimlerarray = res.getStringArray(R.array.asker_anabaslik);


        ozellikler1 = res.getString(R.string.barbarozellikleri1);
        ozellikler2 = res.getString(R.string.barbarozellikleri2);
        ozellikler3 = res.getString(R.string.barbarozellikleri3);
        ozellikler4 = res.getString(R.string.barbarozellikleri4);
        ozellikler5 = res.getString(R.string.barbarozellikleri5);


        // get views
        final ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.askerdetay_icon);
        final TextView txtanabaslik = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.anatextview);

        final TextView fvcvp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.favoricvp);
        final TextView hsrcvp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hasarcvp);
        final TextView alan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.barinmacvp);
        final TextView hiz = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hizcvp);
        final TextView egitim = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.egitimcvp);

        // set data
        img.setImageResource(resimler[pos]);
        txtanabaslik.setText(isimlerarray[pos]);

        fvcvp.setText(ozellikler1);
        hsrcvp.setText(ozellikler2);
        alan.setText(ozellikler3);
        hiz.setText(ozellikler4);
        egitim.setText(ozellikler5);

        ileri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = pos + 1;

                if (position < resimler.length) {
                    img.setImageResource(resimler[position]);
                    txtanabaslik.setText(isimlerarray[position]);
                    fvcvp.setText(ozellikler1);
                    hsrcvp.setText(ozellikler2);
                    alan.setText(ozellikler3);
                    hiz.setText(ozellikler4);
                    egitim.setText(ozellikler5);
                    pos += 1;

                }
            }
        });

        geri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = pos - 1;

                if (!(position < 0)) {

                    img.setImageResource(resimler[position]);
                    txtanabaslik.setText(isimlerarray[position]);

                    fvcvp.setText(ozellikler1);
                    hsrcvp.setText(ozellikler2);
                    alan.setText(ozellikler3);
                    hiz.setText(ozellikler4);
                    egitim.setText(ozellikler5);
                    pos -= 1;

                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

genel_tab_layout.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#607D8B">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/anatextview"
        />



</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        >



        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GERİ"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/geri_btn"
            />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500px"
        android:layout_height="500px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/askerdetay_icon"

        />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="İLERİ"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ileri_btn"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

           >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Favori Hedef:"
        android:id="@+id/TextFavori"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hasar Türü:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextFavori"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextHasar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Barınma Alanı:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextHasar"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextBarinma"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hareket Hızı:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextBarinma"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/TextHiz"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Eğitim Süresi:"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextHiz"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/TextEgitimSuresi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/favoricvp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hasarcvp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/barinmacvp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hizcvp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/egitimcvp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           />



    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Genel Özellikleri"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="yazılar"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```